# Detect if a div is in the center and execute some code

Tags: jquery, html, center

i need to detect if a div is in the center of the screen and then execute some code - im currently using offset but if the monitor has a high resolution its useless.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//check to see if elements are at a certain position
$(document).ready(function () {
//hide bubble
$('#bubble02').hide();
// if div is at 300px execute code
  var videoInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if($('#balloon2').offset().left <= 300){
    $('#bubble02').fadeIn();
  }  
  else if($('#balloon2').offset().left >= 301){
    $('#bubble02').fadeOut();
  } 
});
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the window width with [$(window).width();](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and check if the offset of the div equals half the width :

```
var windowCenter =  $(window).width() / 2;
if($('#balloon2').offset().left <= windowCenter){
    $('#bubble02').fadeIn();
}  
else if($('#balloon2').offset().left >= windowCenter){
    $('#bubble02').fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: @user1546292 Please validate my answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Validated! - just quickly is there a better way to constantly check for theses variables other than using setInterval(function() ?

Comment: @user1546292 How does your code work ? The div is moving and you want to know when it's in the center ? I can't think of another way than setInterval. Just set the interval according to the accuracy you need, like, every 1000 milliseconds so that your function doesn't run all the time. Also take the windowCenter calculation out of this setInterval function. It only has to run once !

Comment: @alib0ng0 You can use window.onscroll callback to do that if you want it as the view is scrolled